# React Higher Order Component Initial Props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a player library and want the React flow to go like this:

`PlayerHOC -> PlaylistHOC -> FooterContainer`.

The reason I want it to go in this direction is that `PlayerHOC` has methods on it that `PlaylistHOC` and `FooterContainer` need to access (i.e from props).

My code:

```
class FooterContainer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="jp-type-footer" >
                    //...
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class FooterPlayer extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.options = {
            smoothPlayBar: false,
            muted: true,
            //...
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Player {...this.options} />
        );
    }
};

export const PlaylistHOC = (WrappedComponent) => class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        //Add a new stateClass for the extra loop option
        this.stateClass = merge({
            shuffled: "state-shuffled", 
            loopedPlaylist: "state-loop-playlist"
        }, this.props.stateClass);   
    }
    setPlaylist = () => {}
};

export const PlayerHOC = (WrappedComponent) => class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        //get passed in props from FooterPlayer and PlaylistHoc
    }
    play = () => {}
    pause = () => {}
};

const Player = PlayerHOC(PlaylistHOC(FooterContainer));

export default connect()(FooterPlayer);
```

I also pass in props from `FooterPlayer` to `PlayerHOC` which works fine. However, I also want to pass in default props from `PlaylistHOC` to `PlayerHOC` that will never be updated and I can't figure out how to this while also keeping this flow.

For example: `const Player = PlaylistHOC(PlayerHOC(FooterContainer));` this would allow me to pass in initial props from `PlaylistHOC` and `FooterPlayer` to `PlayerHOC` but then I would not be able to access `PlayerHOC` methods by props.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `const Player = PlaylistHOC(PlayerHOC(FooterContainer));` because a parent component can't receive props from it's children.

Looks like both `PlaylistHOC` and `PlayerHOC` are mixins, so they should inherit from the component being wrapped instead of `React.Component`.

I've changed a code just a little bit to be able to test it, but the key idea of it is how I've extended `WrappedComponent` instead of `React.Component` in your mixins.

```
class FooterContainer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="jp-type-footer">
                    <button onClick={this.play.bind(this)}>Play</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class FooterPlayer extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.options = {
            smoothPlayBar: false,
            muted: true
            //...
        };
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Player {...this.options} />
        );
    }
};

export const PlaylistHOC = (WrappedComponent) => class extends WrappedComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        //Add a new stateClass for the extra loop option
        //this.stateClass = merge({
        //      shuffled: "state-shuffled",
        //    loopedPlaylist: "state-loop-playlist"
        //}, this.props.stateClass);
    }
    setPlaylist() {

    }
};

export const PlayerHOC = (WrappedComponent) => class extends WrappedComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        //get passed in props from FooterPlayer and PlaylistHoc
    }
    play() {
      console.log('playing');
    }
    pause() {

    }
};

const Player = PlaylistHOC(PlayerHOC(FooterContainer));

export default connect()(FooterPlayer);
```

By the way, try [decorators](https://medium.com/google-developers/exploring-es7-decorators-76ecb65fb841#.7ffvoiue9) for some really fancy syntax like

```
@PlayerlistHOC
@PlayerHOC
class FooterContainer {

}
```

Be warned decorators are not definitive and might change a lot.

Comment: Good idea but both methods return undefined. Also `WrappedComponent()` throws an error. so I don't think I can do it this way.

Comment: I just realized `WrappedComponent` is a reference to the class, not an instance of it, and as it relies on prototypical inheritance the methods should be available on the `prototype`. Try the new code

Comment: This doesn't work either and seems like a hacky way of just using `Refs` which I was trying to avoid

Comment: Finally had time to properly try this out, hope it helps this time :)

Comment: That works, thanks a lot. I just found out that this is [Inheritance Inversion](https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.i7atke3rs). React says we should prefer composition over [inheritance](https://discuss.reactjs.org/t/best-practices-for-extending-subclassing-components/1820/2). Should I just be using refs + composition instead? Or is this fine with HOC's?

Comment: All of them are valid as long as you know their advantages. Mixins and HOCs are very similar, but clearly the HOC pattern looks more clean and powerful to me. I never use refs, i rather have components behave like views and delegate the encapsulation of the application and it's state to Redux, so instead of using a ref you fire an action that eventually changes an element's properties. Encapsulating the UI can be more challenging for me because React implements OOP by the book when it comes to components and their relations, and I personally don't like classical OOP, but thats just an opinion

Comment: React works with classes and forces you into the OOP madness of Taxonomy, Classical Inheritance, and you might end up with a 7 layer wrapper in top of a simple UI component that will be painful to understand 3 months later. Thankfully it is hard to get into that kind of scenario when the only thing you're using classes for are UI components. JavaScript doesn't force you to use types and inheritance and the less of them you use the more you realize how bad the OOP paradigm actually is. That being said, React is the most brilliant UI framework out there.